# Grabbing Tumblr images and implementing the infinite scroll feature

Tags: jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll, pastebin

Evening,

I've come to a dead end with this, I've managed to import Tumblr post images to my theme and managed to get Infinite-Scroll function working aswell. The only problem the infinite scroll loops the tumblr images instead of getting the next set of images e.g getting offset 10 on each scroll instead of looping 10 images over and over.

Here is the code, pastebin URL: http://pastebin.com/8GTtaMeX

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fast example how you can do this easily with jQ
http://jsbin.com/ijehog/edit#preview

Edit: Wups failed with the offset :) http://jsbin.com/ijehog/2/edit#preview